# Cache locality with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, caching, vector

I have a vector of custom classes (std::string just for example).

The vector is large and I iterate through often, so I rely on cache locality.

I also have one raw pointer which points at one of the vector elements.

Now is the trick:

The vector is sorted from time to time, so the raw pointer loose the actual pointed element value, and will point to some random element value.

Here is an example to illustrate the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> v = {"9","3", "8", "7", "6", "5", "1", "4", "2"};

    string* rs = &v[7]; //point to the 7th element

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cerr << v[i];
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string: " << rs->c_str() << endl;

    cerr << "Sort ..." << endl;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const string& a, const string& b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cerr << v[i];
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string: " << rs->c_str() << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
938765142
Referenced string before sort : 4
Sort ...
123456789
Referenced string after sort : 8
```

Since I wish the *rs* pointer to keep pointing to the 7th element value (which is 4) even after the sort, I came up with the following solution (vector of pointers):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    vector<unique_ptr<string>> v;
    v.resize(9);
    v[0] = make_unique<string>("9");
    v[1] = make_unique<string>("3");
    v[2] = make_unique<string>("8");
    v[3] = make_unique<string>("7");
    v[4] = make_unique<string>("6");
    v[5] = make_unique<string>("5");
    v[6] = make_unique<string>("1");
    v[7] = make_unique<string>("4");
    v[8] = make_unique<string>("2");

    string* rs = v[7].get();        

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    cerr << v[i]->c_str();
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string before sort: " << rs->c_str() << endl;


    cerr << "Sort ..." << endl;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const unique_ptr<string>& a, const unique_ptr<string>& b)
    {
    if (*a < *b)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
    }
    );



    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    cerr << v[i]->c_str();
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string after sort: " << rs->c_str() << endl;


    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
938765142
Referenced string before sort: 4
Sort ...
123456789
Referenced string after sort: 4
```

While this latter solution works, there is a price: I have lost the cache locality of my vector, since I store pointers in it, rather than the actual objects.

Is there a way to maintain cache locality (e.g.: store my actual objects in the vector), and somehow manage to *rs* pointer to keep track where its pointed value wander around due to the sorts?
Or from the other perspective, is there a way to achieve cache locality with the vector of pointers?

Solution from Pubby, thanks!:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> data = { "d","e", "f", "g", "i", "b", "c", "a", "h" };
    vector<int> indexes = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};


    int si = 6;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i)
        cerr << indexes[i];
    cerr << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i)
        cerr << data[indexes[i]];
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string before sort: " << data[si] << endl;

    cerr << "Sort ..." << endl;
    sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](const int a, const int b)
    {
        return data[a] < data[b];
    }
    );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i)
        cerr << indexes[i];
    cerr << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i)
        cerr << data[indexes[i]];
    cerr << endl;
    cerr << "Referenced string after sort: " << data[si] << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can increase locality by storing the strings in a vector which *doesn't* change, and then store a vector of pointers/indexes to these strings.

Like this:

```
vector<string> data = {"9","3", "8", "7", "6", "5", "1", "4", "2"};
vector<unsigned> indexes(data.size());
std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0u);
```

To sort your data you'd sort `indexes` using a custom comparator function which retrieves the values from `data` and compares them. Remember: `indexes` can change, but `data` should not!

```
sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](unsigned a, unsigned b)
    {
        return data[a] < data[b];
    });
```

Comment: I work with rdbms all the day, and i didn't realize their most basic feature: indexing, and exactly the way you described, thank you, this is what I will try to implement now

Comment: I am posting full code your solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Instead of storing `std::string` in the vector, just append the character arrays of each string to a `std::vector<char>`.

This packs the strings closely together in memory, improving locality even better than `std::string` with small string optimization. It will also give better results if the strings exceed the max. size for small string optimization.

For sorting, store index and size of each string in a 2nd vector similar to Pubbys suggestion.

Of course this only works if the string length doesn't need to change dynamically. Otherwise you would have to rebuild the `vector<char>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

using IndexAndSize = pair<size_t,size_t>;

void push_and_index( vector<char>& v, vector<IndexAndSize>& vi, string_view s )
{
    vi.emplace_back( v.size(), s.size() );
    v.insert( end(v), begin(s), end(s) );
}

string_view make_string_view( vector<char> const& v, IndexAndSize is )
{
    return { v.data() + is.first, is.second };
}

int main()
{
    vector<char> v;
    vector<IndexAndSize> vi;

    push_and_index( v, vi, "foo" );
    push_and_index( v, vi, "bar" );
    push_and_index( v, vi, "foobar" );
    push_and_index( v, vi, "barfoo" );

    sort( begin(vi), end(vi), [&]( IndexAndSize a, IndexAndSize b )
    {
        return make_string_view( v, a ) < make_string_view( v, b );
    });

    for( IndexAndSize is : vi )
    {
        cout << make_string_view( v, is ) << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo on Coliru.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pXvYuoBsZbU9srRm)

Note: C++17's [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is used only to help with the sorting and output, it's not crucial for this idea.

Comment: thanks, yes the indexing is a good idea, but the string object was just an example, i have custom classes